# codeigniter model - return 2 sets of results - how to?

Tags: codeigniter

What I am trying to do:

I have a search box, and one can search for posts or username or user e-mail.

Posts are in one table, users are in another.

Here is the structure:

Posts

post_id
user_id
post
post_date
visible

Users

userid
username
email
firstname
lastname

Now, I am trying the following code in my model:

```
<?php

 public function posts_that_match_search_term($search_term) {


$post_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts,users WHERE post_message LIKE '%$search_term%' AND post_user_id=user_id  ORDER BY post_id DESC", array());

$post_query2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username LIKE '%$search_term%' OR user_email LIKE '%$search_term%'  ORDER BY user_id DESC", array());


if ($post_query->num_rows() == 0) {
    return array();
} else {
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($post_query->result() AS $row) {
        $post_array[$i]["post_id"] = $row->post_id;
        $post_array[$i]["post_message"] = $row->post_message;

        $post_array[$i]["post_datetime"] = $row->post_datetime;
        $post_array[$i]["post_completion_status"] = $row->post_completion_status;
        $post_array[$i]["post_completion_date"] = $row->post_completion_date;
        $post_array[$i]["post_completion_notes"] = $row->post_completion_notes;
    }

    return $post_array;
}

if ($post_query2->num_rows() == 0) {
    return array();
} else {
    $a = 0;

    foreach ($post_query2->result() AS $row2) {

        $post_array2[$a]["user_id"] = $row2->user_id;
        $post_array2[$a]["user_name"] = $row2->user_name;
        $post_array2[$a]["user_username"] = $row2->user_username;
        $post_array2[$a]["user_image_filename"] = $row2->user_image_filename;
        $post_array2[$a]["user_first_name"] = $row2->user_first_name;
        $post_array2[$a]["user_last_name"] = $row2->user_last_name;
        $post_array2[$a]["user_email"] = $row2->user_email;





        $a++;
    }

    return $post_array2;
}
}
```

/* note =  code is shortened on some places for sake of simplicity */

Both queryes works and return results if I run them one by one. That is if I comment the first query and all the code after if ($post_query->num_rows() == 0) { then second part of  code works normally and return results. Same is true for opposite.

Any help will be deeply appreciate.

Regards, Zoran

When both are uncommented, I am getting no error, just 0 results.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Zoran,
You have to make one query that checks for both username or email. Do you know how to make joins like so:

```
$this->db->join('posts', posts.userid = users.userid');
```

So you join the two tables, and then search them for username OR email. Let me know what you come up with!

Comment: Hi Dirk I need 2 queries. The userid from the first query is just to get which user post the posts. The second query should check if some username or e-mail match the search term

Comment: No, not the way I see it, or your approach is wrong... What is your desired outcome? As I understand, you want people to fill in something in a search box, and your function searches for username or e-mail and returns the posts that correspond to that search term, right? You need 1 query for that that searches both tables, regardless of the search term being a username or email address.

Comment: So if someone search for lorem ipsum...I want the posts that contain lorem ipsum to be displayed. However, if there is user named Lorem, I want both , the post and the user. First: search results: posts and then the posts that contain search term. When done with posts, on same page I want : search results: people and there the data of all users that have Lorem in the user name or in their emails

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Can't you do a fulltext search then? The fulltext query searches for any occuring $searchterm in the tables, and you can group them by post content, username and email. Some more info on fulltext search and codeigniter: http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2009/10/fulltext-search-with-mysql-and-codeigniter/